# NSDateComponentsFormatter future time +1.998730003833771 results in "1 second" string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I have manually created a date in the future, with this code:

```
[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: s + 60*m + 60*60*h ];
```

I pass in 2 for "s", and 0 for "m" and "h".  The result is a NSDate object that is exactly 2 seconds in the future.

Then a few function calls later, I attempt to get a string for that date using an NSDateComponentsFormatter.  I make the following calls:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.locale = self.locale;
calendar.timeZone = self.timeZone;
NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;

NSDateComponents* deltaComponents = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:to options:0];
deltaComponents.calendar = calendar;

NSString *result = [self.componentFormatter stringFromDateComponents:deltaComponents];
```

The problem is that by the time I am calling

```
[calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:to options:0];
```

There has been a very small change in time!  Setting a log like this, shows us the issue:

```
NSLog(@"TIME INTERVAL SINCE NOW: %@",@([date timeIntervalSinceNow]));
1.998730003833771
```

The resultant string:

**"1 second"**

Here you can see my frustration.  I would like the NSDateComponentsFormatter to round this small difference to "2 seconds", but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Then a few function calls later,... The problem is that by the time...

Just save the original value of `[NSDate date]` before calling `datebyAddingTimeInterval` and then use that value instead of calling `[NSDate date]` again.

Any attempt to round etc. sounds like a "fudge factor", and they are never good to employ.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding exactly `2` seconds, add `2.99` seconds. That will make all the differences to be rounded up.

Or you can add `2.5` for common rounding (< 0.5 will round down, > 0.5 will round up).

Comment: Strangely, neither of those solutions works (2.99 or 2.5).  The result from this statement:

    NSLog(@"TIME INTERVAL SINCE NOW: %@",@([date timeIntervalSinceNow]));

Is still 

    1.998730003833771

Comment: @ermterm You will also have to add `NSCalendarUnitSecond` to your `units`, otherwise you are truncating anything lower than a second.

Comment: If you scroll horizontally in the code section of my initial response, you will see that the "NSCalendarUnitSecond" value is there.  :(

Comment: @ermterm I meant NSCalendarUnitNanosecond